# Udev monitor does not display any event on If I mount or unmount a partition

Tags: linux, mount, udev

I observing `udevadm monitor` to detect when the usb is un-mounted, or partition (USB) is removed.

if the partition `/dev/sda1` is mounted at `/mnt/mydisk`

If I remove the partition `/dev/sda1` via physically removing the USB stick. I see remove event appearing on `udevadm monitor` but if try to just `umount` the disk `/mnt/mydisk`.

`umount /mnt/mydisk`

**No event** of changes appear in `udevadm monitor`. Likewise the event for mount also **does not** show up on `monitor`

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/mydisk
```

Is it even possible to get such changes event in `udev`.

I have **no udev rule** laid in `/etc/udev/rules.d`